# Firebase cloud functions direct app calling on client

Tags: reactjs, firebase, client, google-cloud-functions

I am unable to access firebase functions directly on the client side following the [steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). I have configured exactly the same in my React Client app

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase-functions'

require('dotenv').config()


var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBAES_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID 
};

// Firebase is being initialized
let fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Firestore is also working
let firestore = firebase.firestore()

// But when I tried to initiate functions it is failing
let functions = firebase.functions()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Or is just nothing happening?

Comment: Are you on the very latest version of the Firebase SDK (4.12.0) -- this is a brand-new feature that was just released.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda the error `Uncaught TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function`

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Yes, I am using (4.12.0) I have double checked it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing the `firebase-functions` Node.js library, not the callable functions part of the SDK. Your imports should look like:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/functions'
```

Comment: Has this changed? I'm doing exactly this today and it's giving me the same "firebase.functions is not a function"

Comment: You need to add an _at_ before, like: `import '@firebase/firestore'`